# Need the proof of Lemma 7.3.7 in "Finite fields: structure and arithmetics" by D. Jungnickel

Tags: characters

I am unable to find a copy of "Finite fields: structure and arithmetics" by D. Jungnickel in a library and I would like to read the proof of Lemma 7.3.7 in that book which states that for an odd prime power $q$ and $a \in \mathbf{F}_q^*$, $$\sum_{x \in \mathbf{F}_q} \eta(x)\eta(x+a)=-1$$ where $\eta$ is the quadratic character of $\mathbf{F}_q$. Can anyone share the scan of the proof?

Answer (score 4):

I can not offer a scan but it seems pretty easy to prove (for $\eta$ non-trivial):

For notational sake let us put $$F_{\eta}(a) = \sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_q}\eta(x)\eta(x+a),$$ for $a\in \mathbb{F}_q$. We first compute $$F_{\eta}(0)= \sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_q}\eta(x)^2 = q-1.$$ Here we used $\eta(0)=0$ and that $\eta$ is quadratic. Now I claim that $F(a)=F(b)$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb{F}_q^{\times}$. This is just a change of variables: $$F_{\eta}(a) = \sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_q}\eta(x)\eta(x+a) = \sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_q}\eta(ax)\eta(ax+a) = \eta(a)^2\sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_q}\eta(x)\eta(x+1) =\eta(a)^2F_{\eta}(1) = F_{\eta}(1).$$ Again we used that $\eta$ is quadratic. We can finally finish the proof: $$F_{\eta}(a) = \frac{1}{q-1}\sum_{a\in \mathbb{F}_q^{\times}}F_{\eta}(a) =  \frac{1}{q-1}\sum_{a\in \mathbb{F}_q}F_{\eta}(a) - 1 = \frac{1}{q-1}\sum_{x\in \mathbb{F}_q}\eta(x) \sum_{a\in\mathbb{F}_q}\eta(x+a) - 1 = \frac{1}{q-1}\sum_{x\in \mathbb{F}_q}\eta(x) \sum_{a\in\mathbb{F}_q}\eta(a) - 1 = -1.$$ Where we used character orthogonality in the last step. This conlcudes the proof.